# MongoDB and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

Can anyone assist in pointing me to a tutorial, library, etc. that will allow me to work with MongoDB from CodeIgniter?

Comment: check this out
https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library

Comment: I have a doubt. Mongodb query syntax is already simple. There is no need to write complex SQL's. Why don't you disable "ActiveRecord" class in config and write your own queries using default mongo driver?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the "CodeIgniter way" but I created a CodeIgniter library that extends the Mongo class with an extra property to store the current database connection.

Here are the relevant code files from my project.

**config/mongo.php**

```
$config['mongo_server'] = null;
$config['mongo_dbname'] = 'mydb';
```

**libraries/Mongo.php**

```
class CI_Mongo extends Mongo
{
    var $db;

    function CI_Mongo()
    {   
        // Fetch CodeIgniter instance
        $ci = get_instance();
        // Load Mongo configuration file
        $ci->load->config('mongo');

        // Fetch Mongo server and database configuration
        $server = $ci->config->item('mongo_server');
        $dbname = $ci->config->item('mongo_dbname');

        // Initialise Mongo
        if ($server)
        {
            parent::__construct($server);
        }
        else
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        $this->db = $this->$dbname;
    }
}
```

And a sample controller

**controllers/posts.php**

```
class Posts extends Controller
{
    function Posts()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $posts = $this->mongo->db->posts->find();

        foreach ($posts as $id => $post)
        {
            var_dump($id);
            var_dump($post);
        }
    }

    function create()
    {
        $post = array('title' => 'Test post');
        $this->mongo->db->posts->insert($post);
        var_dump($post);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stephen

What about models? Is there any special consideration that has to be given there?

Comment: I was able to get the models functionality working also. Nothing special, still inherit from Model and your functions just have to call Mongo specific functions. Easy

Comment: Exactly.  You should be able to go $this->mongo->db directly in your model code.

Comment: This is great stuff are there any plans to release more documentation or to expand on how to search and retrieve documents?

Comment: Its the Mongo DB PHP driver. So you'd use the library as you would normally outside of CodeIgniter. Have you seen the Mongo DB PHP driver doc? http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

Comment: note that the mongo object already has a `connection` property natively.

Comment: Thanks for this Stephen, i was just curious, do you know what `parent::__construct($server);` does ?

Comment: It invokes the parent constructor, in this case the constructor of the Mongo class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php), passing in the host name/ip address of where the Mongo DB server is running.

Comment: $ci =& get_instance() should be used instead. From CI docs: This is very important. Assigning by reference allows you to use the original CodeIgniter object rather than creating a copy of it.

Comment: @StephenCurran I have a doubt. Mongodb query syntax is already simple. There is no need to write complex SQL's. Why don't you disable "ActiveRecord" class in config and write your own queries using default mongo driver?

Comment: Hi, my settings were already made for mysql, and now I am trying to change them for mongodb. I also have libraries\Mysmarty.php and in config\database a have set $db['default']['database'] = 'application';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';.........What should I do with these ones? If a just delete "mysql" and relace it with "mongo" it does not work

Answer (score 15):

MongoDB is very well supported within CodeIgniter community, take the time and dive in :p

- [CodeIgniter MongoDB Active Document Library](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2)  **[BROKEN LINK]**
- [CodeIgniter MongoDB Session Library](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-session)  **[OBSOLETE]**
- [CodeIgniter MongoDB Authentication Library](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-ionauth)    **[OBSOLETE]**
- [CodeIgniter MongoDB REST Server Library](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-restserver)    **[OBSOLETE]**
- [CodeIgniter MongoDB Base Model](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-base-model)  **[OBSOLETE]**

Comment: Thank you. Two years ago there wasn't much but I agree that support for Mongo is much better now.

Comment: https://amit-tips-for-techie.blogspot.com/2023/04/connect-codeigniter-with-mongodb.html

Answer (score 11):

I like Stephen Curran's example as it is simple and allows an interface to Mongo without too much functionality written within Php, I tend to find huge abstraction clases a bit much at times for what I am after.

I have extended his example to include database authentication. Go here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication to read about mongo authentication, don't forget to enable authentication for the Mongo Server you are connecting to.

I have also changed the old style constructor function to be __construct and am handling Mongo Connection Exceptions as they can reveal your username and password.

#### config/mongo.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['mongo_server'] = 'localhost';
$config['mongo_dbname'] = 'my_mongo_db';
$config['mongo_username'] = 'mongo_user';
$config['mongo_password'] = 'password1234';

/* End of file mongo.php */
```

#### libraries/Mongo.php

```
<?php

class CI_Mongo extends Mongo{

    protected $db;

    function __construct()
    {   
        // Fetch CodeIgniter instance
        $ci = get_instance();
        // Load Mongo configuration file
        $ci->load->config('mongo');

        // Fetch Mongo server and database configuration
        $server = $ci->config->item('mongo_server');
        $username = $ci->config->item('mongo_username');
        $password = $ci->config->item('mongo_password');
        $dbname = $ci->config->item('mongo_dbname');

        // Initialise Mongo - Authentication required
        try{
            parent::__construct("mongodb://$username:$password@$server/$dbname");
            $this->db = $this->$dbname;
        }catch(MongoConnectionException $e){
            //Don't show Mongo Exceptions as they can contain authentication info
            $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
            exit($_error->show_error('MongoDB Connection Error', 'A MongoDB error occured while trying to connect to the database!', 'error_db'));           
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
            exit($_error->show_error('MongoDB Error',$e->getMessage(), 'error_db'));           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a little if() would help for if there are no auth cred. given ;)

Comment: Possibly, however if a user wants to run against a mongo server without the --auth flag then they could just use the original post by Stephen Curran. Or adapt mine as necessary. Luke

Answer (score 6):

Working with MongoDB in CodeIgniter wouldn't be much different than working with it anywhere else.

You could knock together a MongoDB library that would connect in the constructor and store $this->conn to be used in methods later on.

then either work directly with the conn property in your controllers or create a few methods in your MongoDB library to do this for you.

Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) to see the plain PHP tutorial for working with MongoDB.

I'd happily create you a library for this but it would come with a price. :-p

Comment: thank you - i realize that with the MongoDB Driver and the above PHP tutorial i can make it all happen.

Comment: If you create a good library please share it with the community. Id love an excuse to play with MongoDB. :-)

Comment: @Phil Sturgeon - looks like @stephenc beat me to it.

Comment: Sweet, I only wish I had the time to make one myself. :-) Looks cool.

Comment: Sorry am I being thick? Where's the library from @stephenc?

Comment: @Piers just shared a library in the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248789/mongodb-and-codeigniter/4865588#4865588

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MongoDB w/ CI and came up with the following. It works for me, but I'm sure it can be tweaked somewhat. I'll worry about tweaking it later but right now it does what I want.

I created a model called "database_conn.php"

```
class Database_Conn extends Model {

    function _connect() {
        $m = new Mongo();

        $db = $m->selectDB( "YOUR DATABASE NAME" );
        return $db;
    }
}
```

Then, if I need to connect to a collection from my models.

```
$collection = Database_Conn::_connect()->selectCollection( "COLLECTION NAME" );
```