# Inserting multiple json elements into MongoDB database

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have connected my php web app to mongodb with the help of codeigniter driver. Trying to inserting multiple json elements into database as below.

```
"ticket" : [
     {
     "problem" : "testing",
     "time_taken" : "5 hrs",
     "number_of_visits" : "7",
     "expenses" : {
             "amount" : "2000",
             "distance_travelled" : "4 km"
              }
     },
     {
     "problem" : "testing",
     "time_taken" : "5 hrs",
     "number_of_visits" : "4",
     "expenses" : {
             "amount" : "2500",
             "distance_travelled" : "5 km"
              }
     }
]
```

What is the query I have to use for this?

Comment: Visit [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139190/where-to-insert-functions-in-codeigniter-mongodb ]

Comment: @ManthanDave - Except it's MongoDB, not mySQL ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->mongo_db->where('_id', new MongoId($id))->push("ticket",$data)->update('engineer');

This is the query I'm using for inserting multiple array values in mongodb codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Bulk Write functions (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)

The PHP depends on which library you are using (old or new, hopefully the new one!) but in plain English you:

- create an array of operations (in your case "inserts")
- call bulk write.

Comment: Well, you've obviously done something wrong, but I'm afraid my crystal ball isn't showing me what you've done. So not really in a position to help...