# How to connect with the MongoDB through CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, ubuntu-16.04

I am upgrading my Ubuntu server and installing latest version of PHP i.e PHP 7.0.18, MongoDB 3.2.14, CodeIgniter v 2.2. Now when I am trying to connect with Mongo through CodeIgniter I am getting error as:

> The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled.

Kindly help. Kindly note my MongoDB and app are in two different instances. From app instance through CLI I can access the MongoDB but through CodeIgniter I am not able to.

Actually I am not able to update the lib file which I am using as per the updated versions.

Thanks.

Comment: Here a nice and easy tutorial 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248789/mongodb-and-codeigniter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB and CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248789/mongodb-and-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `php.ini` and search for the `extension` and pass the proper extension path like:

```
extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so"
```

uncomment it by removing the `;` from the starting and restart the apache and try again.