# Configure Codeigniter-3.1.10 to use mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, codeigniter-3

I am trying to make use of `mongodb` in a LAMP setup in my machine. The tech specs I have been using are:

```
OS: Linux(Ubuntu-16.04LTS)
PHP Version: PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
mongo version: Percona Server for MongoDB shell version v3.4.18-2.16
PHP Framework: CodeIgnitor-3.1.10
```

Following are the things I tried:

1. I used [this library](https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library) to connect mongo database but did not work well.
2. I used the code method as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248789/mongodb-and-codeigniter).

Whenever I tried [this file](https://gist.github.com/chalisekrishna418/e31694e9220618f4fc5cf6d47bf3c1b3) as library and configured to autoload the library then I encountered this issue:

> Class 'MongoClient' not found.

Comment: Can you share the exact code you've used?

Comment: I have not been to a phase where I can start writing a controller as the setup provided in `the things I tried` section does not seem to work for me. I am looking for the proper setup.

Comment: I'm just asking because you've shared an error message. There must be some code given to lead you to that message, and that message does not look like the setup already went wrong

Comment: @NicoHaase Please find the updated question with the library file that I used and autoloaded.

Comment: Please share your code here in text form. Try do reduce it to the minimum parts triggering your problem, and avoid using only links to provide such information